# pub/sub pattern in javascript versus websocket

Tags: javascript, publish-subscribe

I often confused with pubsub design pattern versus protocol like websocket. When new jargon come like reactive programming I became even more confused. To me it's like WebSocket is a kind of pubsub, but I don't know beyond WebSocket if I want to explore more about pubsub pattern.

if it's frontend I don't have to use external library to do pubsub, because my state management of any framework like react 'is' already pubsub in a way..

**My question is** what is pubsub in javascript and what's the practicality of it

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: @jmargolisvt my question is what is pubsub in javascript and what's the practicality of it.

Comment: Please add links to the resources you've googled that fail to explain it to you.  Add specific details to your question about what is unclear to you from those resources .

Comment: WebSocket is first of all a transport method. PubSub is a pattern to distribute information. The way you send and receive the data in WebSockets is similar to how PubSub pattern works, but not with the granularity you normally expect from a PubSub pattern. The reason for that is that WebSockets are event-based, and the same applies to pubsub.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of WebSockets as a transportation method, like a plane. It solves the problem of getting the client and server to talk in real-time (e.g. chat applications, notifications, etc). There are other methods like long-short polling (bus), or server-sent events (train).

PubSub is a design pattern on how pieces of a system communicate. It's like the subway/airplane system (think JetBlue, Delta Airlines, NYC Subway System, etc). Common tools to handle PubSub today are Kafka and Redis. Some Backend engineers can build an entire career out of designing well-architected, reliable PubSub systems. It can be a very difficult problem.

Reactive programming (RxJS) is a programming style, similar to how procedural/functional/declarative programming are all unique styles. It's usually used in highly interactive apps where the client needs to update in real-time based on multiple events (e.g. an online Bitcoin trading platform, or adding hotkeys to a webapp).